# .htaccess rewrite not consistent with cookie drop

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have in my .htaccess file the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|af|fr)/(.*)$ - [co=lang:$1:mysite.info:7200:/] #drop/update cookie with lang
RewriteRule ^(en|af|fr)$ - [co=lang:$1:mysite.info:7200:/] #drop/update cookie with lang
RewriteRule ^(en|af|fr)$    / [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^(en|af|fr)/(.*)$ /$2 [R,NC]
```

In my php I have this for selecting the language:

```
<?php echo $_COOKIE['lang']; ?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/en<? echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">en-ZA</a></li>
    <li><a href="/fr<? echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">fr-MU</a></li>
    <li><a href="/af<? echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">af-ZA</a></li>
</ul>
```

It semi-works, but it's not consistent.  While I'm switching between languages it simply stops working, and then starts again if I keep clicking on the different languages.

SECOND PART of question:

How to reduce these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.mysite.info [nc] #if url starts with www.mysite.info
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.info/$1 [r,nc] #rewrite without the www

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.(.*).mysite.info [nc] #if url starts with www.(aff).mysite.info
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.mysite.info/$1 [r,nc] #rewrite without the www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(.*)\.mysite.info [nc] #if subdomain is aff
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [co=aff:%1:mysite.info:7200:/] #drop/update cookie with aff

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(.*)\.mysite.info [nc] #if subdomain is aff
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.info/$1 [nc,R] #rewrite without subdomain
```

Appreciate the help, anubhava!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you have repeated rules in there. Try this rule to replace all 4 of your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|af|fr)(/.*)?$ /$2 [co=lang:$1:mysite.info:7200:/,NC,L,R]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^([^.]+)\.mysite\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.info/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.([^.]+)\.mysite\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.mysite.info/$1 [L,R,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^([^.]+)\.mysite.info [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [co=aff:%1:mysite.info:7200:/]
```

Comment: Thanx.  It still isn't consistently working.  But in the meantime I've read somewhere that for SEO it's better not to handle language settings with cookies, and to actually create subfolders for the different languages, so I'm going to use a different approach.
I'm still marking yours as the answer, because you helped me to reduce my code from 4 lines to one.

Comment: I've got another piece in my .htaccess file that might also need reducing, and would appreciate if you could take a look at it for me... if you're interested/willing?

Comment: Yes sure I can help reduce that. Let me know what is your question.